# Div positioning on a canvas with arrows bindings

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, visualization

I'm searching for a little piece of javascript that can attach to a div (in data-x data-y attributes for example) the x,y coordinates of a draggable div. And then be able to draw arrows between them (using a data-targetid attribute?).

If the solution can look like a simple version of [graphview](http://prefuse.org/gallery/graphview/), [jsPlumb](http://morrisonpitt.com/jsPlumb/html/demo.html) or [vizster](http://hci.stanford.edu/jheer/projects/vizster/) but without the complicated library, and only in javascript/html

Comment: I don't understand, be more specific.

Comment: why don't you use jsPlumb, if it is what you are looking for? It is written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

There is a [jQuery version of jsPlumb](http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html), looks like it's 14kb. What you're trying to do isn't default functionality, you're going to need a (somewhat complicated) library to accomplish it. If you're concerned with code bloat I'd start with the [source code of jsPlumb](http://code.google.com/p/jsplumb/) and start pulling out what you don't need.